# Is there a proper algorithm for concatenating strings in a way that multiple strings can be concatenated only in unique combos?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, arraylist

So the premise is that I have 7 descriptors or qualities and I must ask the user how important each quality is compared to the other. So, if I have 7 qualities, for convenience sake I call them 1-7, I need to do something like this...

1 - 2
1 - 3

1 - 4

1 - 5

1 - 6

1 - 7

and then as we continue along, the first number should be knocked off the list and there would now only be 5 comparisons made between 2 and the remaining numbers. Then this continues to the end where the last remaining numbers to be compared are 6-7. This brings the total comparisons to 21.

I have made a method which works but will probably make me the laughingstock of any job interview I try to show this to. I am a first year programmer trying to fast track myself into employment with these side projects, so please understand that I know this is probably terrible, but I am unsure of the best way to do this.

Here is my code, what would you change? The questions variable is an ArrayList along with the results variable. Thank you.

```
 public void makeQuestions(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(0) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(i+1));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
            questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(1) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(i+1));
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++){
            questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(2) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(i+1));
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
            questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(3) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(i+1));
        }
        for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++){
            questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(4) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(i+1));
        }
        questions.add("How do you rate " + results.get(5) + " in importance compared to "+ results.get(6));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great spot for a double for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < questions.size(); j++) {
        // Compare question i against question j
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I dunno why I didn't think of this. Thank you.